# Finding point of tangency between two functions

Tags: calculus

How would I go about determining the point where two functions not intersect, but where they are tangent?

The functions (or rather curves) that I'd like to find that point for are $u^2 + v^2 = c$ and $v = \frac{b}{a}u + \frac{ag}{2} \frac{1}{u}$, where $c>0,a>0,b>0,g>0$.

My idea is the calculate the tangent line function $v(u) = mu + b$ for each of these and set them equal to each other. That is, find the conditions such $v_1(u_{tan}) = v_2(u_{tan})$. But if this is the case, why can't I just set the derivatives of these two functions to each other, i.e. $v_1' = v_2'$ and solve? I saw somewhere that this isn't the right way to do it, and it makes sense. In looking for these conditions, we are looking for the appropriate constants such that these functions are tangent to one other. Which is the way to go?

Comment: It's not "a point where the functions are tangent [to each other, I presume]" a common point of both graphs? Meaning, an intersection point? Am I missing something?

Comment: I suppose... Not sure if I understood you. So there is really 3 kinds of solutions. Where they intersect, in which case there two points. When they are tangent to another, in which case there is one point, and no solution, when they do not touch. I am not sure if it would be considered an intersection, but perhaps it is an intersection because suppose you look at $v_1(u) = +(c-u^2)^{1/2}$ and $v_2(u) = \frac{b}{a} u + \frac{ag}{2u}$, you'd want $v_1(u_{tan}) = v_2(u_{tan})$.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches fail to account for vertical tangents. Leaving that aside, examining the derivatives gives you the slopes of the tangents, but not their locations. You’ll find values of $u$ for which the tangents to the curves are parallel, but you still need some other constraint to ensure that the two lines coincide, namely, that $v_1(u)=v_2(u)$ as well.